# Create new dataframe using globals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

```
price
               price
date    
2010-01-04  34.57282657
2010-01-04  123.900000
2010-01-04  353.6789738
2010-01-04  13.08
2010-01-04  12.45
```

How can I create a first-differenced dataframe for each item in the list below? Code needs to be general.
I tried:

```
listxx  = ["price"]
for x in listxx:
      globals().update({x_first_diff :x.diff().dropna()})
```

```
Expected Output:
price_first_diff 

             price_first_diff 
2010-01-04  
2010-01-04  89.33
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just use again `globals` to access to the dataframe, and formated strings to name the modified dataframe:

```
listxx  = ["price"]
for x in listxx:
      globals().update({f'{x}_first_diff':globals()[x].diff().fillna('')})

price_first_diff
#              price
#date               
#2010-01-04         
#2010-01-04  89.3272
#2010-01-04  229.779
#2010-01-04 -340.599
#2010-01-04    -0.63
```

---

You can also try to use dict comprehension to create the new dataframes, and then update `globals`:

```
listxx  = ["price"]
dc={f'{x}_first_diff' :globals()[x].diff().fillna('') for x in listxx}
globals().update(dc)
```

Comment: I seem to get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: it seems like price column is of type string, try with `astype(float)`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to name the column of the first_differenced dataframe with "first difference volume" or something in the same line? Currently the column name is volume

Comment: No, I was wrong, don't name a variable with spaces inside the name. @arv Better use "_" as the original, or some character like that.